# Getting List of DVD CD-ROMS and Their Label Names

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm looking for a way to get list of DVD or CD-Roms On a PC and also their label names (If any DVD or CD is inserted) using VB-Script.

Currently There are some scripts which return All of Devices' Letters But I only need DVD and CD ROMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DriveType` property of the `Drive` class reports the type of drive. Here are the values for this enumeration:

```
Const DriveTypeUnknown   = 0
Const DriveTypeRemovable = 1
Const DriveTypeFixed     = 2
Const DriveTypeNetwork   = 3
Const DriveTypeOptical   = 4
Const DriveTypeRAMDisk   = 5
```

Just iterate the `Drives` collection of the `FileSystemObject` class. Note that no distinction is made between CD and DVD drives (nor read/write).

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
    If objDrive.DriveType = DriveTypeOptical Then

        ' Attempt to get the volume name. It will only be available if a disc is loaded.
        If objDrive.IsReady Then
            strLabel = objDrive.VolumeName
        Else
            strLabel = "(no disc)"
        End If

        WScript.Echo "Optical Drive = " & objDrive.DriveLetter & ", Label = " & strLabel

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hmm, are you including the `Const`s I listed in your code? They will need to be there as well.

Comment: Thank You Bond, Yes I forgot to include const s ;) It is working like a charm.